# If $E[X]=75 , E[Y]=75,Var(X)=10,Var(Y)=12,Cov(X,Y)=-3$ give an upper bound to (a),(b)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X and Y be a random variables with $$E[X]=75 , E[Y]=75,Var(X)=10,Var(Y)=12,Cov(X,Y)=-3$$
give an upper bound to

(a) P(X > Y + 15)

(b) P(Y > X + 15)

Thanks For any Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the event $\{(X-Y)^2 >15^2\} = \{X-Y > 15\} \cup \{Y-X > 15\}$.

So, $P(X > Y + 15), P(Y > X+15) \leq P( (X-Y)^2 > 15^2) \leq \frac{E[(X-Y)^2]}{15^2}$ by Markov's inequality.

Now, note $E[(X-Y)^2]$ can be computed in terms of the quantities given to you by noting $var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ and $cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$ along with linearity of expectation.

Comment: thanks a lot, now i got it.XD